# Magento2 get product brand option text by value in Plugin

Tags: magento2, attribute-options

I am trying to get the option text from the option value in Plugin, but I can get the value but can't get the text. May I know any way to do so?

app/code/My/Module/Plugin/DefaultItem.php

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Plugin;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;


class DefaultItem
{
protected $productRepository;



public function __construct(
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
)
{
    $this->productRepository=$productRepository;
}


public function aroundGetItemData(\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem $subject, \Closure $proceed, Item $item)
{
    $data = $proceed($item);

    $productId = $item->getProduct()->getEntityId();

    $brand_value = $this->productRepository->getById($productId)->getCustomAttribute('brand')->getValue();


    $atts = [
        "brand" => $brand_value
    ];

    return array_merge($data, $atts);
}
}
```

It only returns 13 to the frontend.. but I do want the text for this value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with the following code:

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Plugin;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product as ProductResourceModel;
use Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;

class DefaultItem
{
    /**
     * @var ProductFactory
     */
    private $productFactory;

    /**
     * @var ProductResourceModel
     */
    private $productResourceModel;

    public function __construct(
        ProductResourceModel $productResourceModel,
        ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->productResourceModel = $productResourceModel;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    public function aroundGetItemData(AbstractItem $subject, \Closure $proceed, Item $item)
    {
        $data = $proceed($item);

        $productId = $item->getProduct()->getEntityId();

        /** @var ProductFactory $productFactory */
        $productFactory = $this->productFactory->create();
        $this->productResourceModel->load($productFactory, $productId);
        $brandValue = $productFactory->getAttributeText('brand');

        $atts = [
            "brand" => $brandValue
        ];

        return array_merge($data, $atts);
    }
}
```

Then remove **generated** directory and re-compile code:

```
rm -rf generated
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: it return error after changed code

Comment: ParseError: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home/xxxx/dev/xxxxx/app/code/My/Module/Plugin/DefaultItem.php:16....

Comment: Uncaught Error: [object Object]

Comment: Yes I replaced it and showed the error

Comment: The code before has a typo (contain a space), please replace the new one I said above

Comment: I removed the space at the first time

Comment: @hill2011 I've updated the solution, please give it a try.